# Why is Zend\Log (ZF2.2) breaking error handler

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Why is Zend\Log breaking the follow error handling function?

```
function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext = null)
{
    global $Logger;
    
    $Logger->log(6 , "Error '$errstr' received.<br>");
    return true;
}

$Logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger;
$Logger->addWriter(new \Zend\Log\Writer\Null);

set_error_handler('error_handler');

trigger_error('a', E_USER_ERROR);
trigger_error('b', E_USER_ERROR);
trigger_error('c', E_USER_ERROR);
trigger_error('d', E_USER_ERROR);

echo 'done.';
```

If you remove the line $Logger->log() the script executes as expected:

> done.

Leave the logging line in the script terminates on the second E_USER_ERROR.

> Fatal error: b in Z:\Workspace\xampp\htdocs\tests\error.php on line 37

Similarly, if you change the error level to E_USER_WARNING:

> Warning: b in Z:\Workspace\xampp\htdocs\tests\error.php on line 37
>
> Warning: c in Z:\Workspace\xampp\htdocs\tests\error.php on line 38
>
> Warning: d in Z:\Workspace\xampp\htdocs\tests\error.php on line 39
>
> done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext = null)
{
    global $Logger;

    $Logger->log(6 , "Error '$errstr' received.<br>");
    set_error_handler ('error_handler');
    return true;
}

$Logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger;
$Logger->addWriter(new \Zend\Log\Writer\Null);

set_error_handler('error_handler');

trigger_error('a', E_USER_ERROR);
trigger_error('b', E_USER_ERROR);
trigger_error('c', E_USER_ERROR);
trigger_error('d', E_USER_ERROR);

echo 'done.';
```

It seems it looses the error handler in the process. Not sure why. Also, bear in mind, that E_USER_ERROR is very much like E_ERROR and is used for emitting unrecoverable errors. So maybe this behaviour is justified after all.

Comment: Good catch and many thanks!  I've submitted this to the ZF2 issue tracker.